# No feasible entry to subprogram shift_left, type error near

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to use the function shift_left() in my project, but I'm getting 2 errors I can't explain:

1. Error: type error near 'shift left'; expected type 'std_logic_vector'

but temp IS a std_logic_vector!

2. Error: no feasible entry for subprogram 'shift_left' found

the signals used in the code are defined as:

```
signal shifted_pixel, temp : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal i_data : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
```

the snippet below is written within a process

```
temp <= "00000000" & i_data;
shifted_pixel <= shift_left(temp, 5);
```

full code below:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;


entity project is
    port (
        i_clk     : in std_logic;
        i_rst     : in std_logic;
        i_start   : in std_logic;
        i_data    : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    );
end project;

architecture rtl of project is
    signal shifted_pixel, temp : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    begin
        process(i_data)
        begin
            temp <= "00000000" & i_data;
            shifted_pixel <= shift_left(temp, 5);
        end process;
end rtl;
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Where function SHIFT_LEFT is declared and it's parameter and return types is depends on the revision of the standard. You can find one for type unsigned for instance in package numeric_std, wherein use would entail type conversions.

Comment: @user1155120 I have tried casting it to unsigned and it didn't change anything. I'm not sure how to check what revision of the standard I am using, but it should be the latest. I am using the libraries "ieee.std_logic_1164.all" and "ieee.numeric_std.all";

Comment: You don't demonstrate failed type conversions in your code. Your entity doesn't analyze (compile), a semicolon is a separator in a list of port declarations not a terminator - the last one should be removed. `shifted_pixel <= std_logic_vector(shift_left(unsigned(temp), 5));` `temp` has to be type unsigned to use the applicable SHIFT_LEFT in package numeric_std. The resulting value has to be compatible with std_logic_vector to assign to `shifted_pixel`.

Comment: A function is characterized by it's parameter(s) type(s) and return type which is dictated by context. Here the return type is required to be std_logic_vector for assignment to shifted pixel. The parameter and return types for the available function SHIFT_LEFT are type unsigned and you have to type convert both the parameter and result, or find a SHIFT_LEFT that works for std_logic_vector (in -2008).

Comment: Ok I see now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shift_left function in numeric_std package takes an unsigned as first argument and it returns an unsigned value.

So you have to cast your values:

```
shifted_pixel <= std_logic_vector(shift_left(unsigned(temp), 5));
```

HTH