# using shift_left() in a function with variables

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I am attempting to implement the `shift_left()` function within a module I'm writing to sum two 32 bit floats. I am not able to get the function call to stop producing red wavy lines.

Please note this code is NOT final, I'm focused on getting vivado/vhdl to be ok with my call of `shift_left()` before moving on. I started out declaring variable eshift as an integer, but after looking up the library it needs to be a natural, yet declaring the variable as a natural isn't sorting it.

It indicates the expectation of `std_logic_vector`, but casting `manB` as unsigned or by itself doesn't resolve that issue. Is it something like the vector I write to is supposed to be larger to allow for the shift?

I also know that concatenating zeros is what has been suggested as the easiest method, but that seems to be if I know how many times I want to do my logical shift ahead of time. Insight on this is extremely welcome, I'm using all the lessons of problem solving in C but something about VHDL seems difficult.

```vhdl
--function to sum
function floatSum(A_in, B_in: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)) return std_logic_vector is
    variable sum                : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    variable expA, expB         : integer;
    variable eshift             : natural;
    variable manA, manB, manNew : std_logic_vector(22 downto 0);
    variable newExp             : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    begin
        expA := conv_integer(A_in(30 downto 23)) - 127;
        expB := conv_integer(B_in(30 downto 23)) - 127;
        manA := A_in(22 downto 0);
        manB := B_in(22 downto 0);

        --tests for exponent cases and shifts the exponents accordingly
        if expA = expB then
            eShift := 0;
            manNew := manA + manB;
        elsif expA > expB then
            eShift := expA - expB;
            sum(30 downto 23) := A_in(30 downto 23);
            --issue is here
            **manNew := shift_left(unsigned(manB), eShift);**
        else
            eShift := expB - expA;
        end if;
    return(sum);
end floatSum;
```

I have checked the answers to [No feasible entry to subprogram shift_left, type error near](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66832409/no-feasible-entry-to-subprogram-shift-left-type-error-near) and casting the `shift_left` call just made it angry about multiple use clauses, and deleting the unsigned cast makes it complain about even more things.

Please provide assistance with VHDL `shift_left()` function.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. It would be simpler if you posted a complete [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You don't show any `library` or `use` clauses that would help us understand your problem. But use of `conv_integer` suggests you are using non standard Synopsys vhdl packages std_logic_unsigned and std_logic_arith. If you also included the actual standard `numeric_std` those can cause conflicts. Have you also looked into the `float_pkg`available in vhdl 2008?

Comment: I apologize for missing the libraries, but yes I have all three of those included. what is the conflict that arises between those libraries?

When I've googled working with floats, it hasn't been very helpful.. essentially what I found suggested no packages were usable and I'd have to write something myself.

Comment: Does Vivado provide a warning associated with the red wavy indication?  See the log file for warnings.  Add this information to the original question body.

Comment: `std_logic_arith` and `numeric_std` both provide signed and unsigned types. Including both packages will make these types invisible and requires a direct reference. I would recommend removing the non standard `std_logic_arith`package and only using numeric_std

Comment: removing `std_logic_arith` did the trick. I was not aware that they would conflict the way that they did. Thank you Tricky and Mike! not sure yet how to mark what worked to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

> std_logic_arith and numeric_std both provide signed and unsigned types. Including both packages will make these types invisible and requires a direct reference. I would recommend removing the non standard std_logic_arith package and only using numeric_std – Tricky

removing the std_logic_arith library resolved my issue.